# Error in compile Sample Service in class MyService.java

Tags: java, nokia

I am a newbie on Nokia development. I tried to create a Service like in  https://projects.developer.nokia.com/notificationsapi/wiki/ServiceSampleJava but I have more problem about that. I tried to compile MyService? .java like this:

```
java -cp .:httpclient-4.0.1.jar:apache-mime4j-0.6.jar:commons-codec-1.3.jar:commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:httpcore-4.0.1.jar:/lib/httpmime-4.0.1.jar MyService? "payload:Test Notification from REST API" "jid:nnapi_testuser@ovi.com" “application_id:com.example” “service_id:example.com” “service_secret:WcbOlf05YCSyy0d4I9nBHSkE+vXRGJxjw90E/KpXLJ0=”
```

I have result errors like this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?:
>   :apache-mime4j-0/6/jar Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException?:
>   :apache-mime4j-0.6.jar
>
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217) at
>   java.security.AccessController?.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader?.loadClass(ClassLoader?.java:321) at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader?.loadClass(Launcher.java:294) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader?.loadClass(ClassLoader?.java:266)
>
> Could not find the main class: :apache-mime4j-0.6.jar. Program will
>   exit.

What can I do to fix these errors?

Comment: This question is extremely hard to read, please clean it up a bit

Answer (score 0):

You're using a colon : to separate your libs. You need to use a semi-colon ;. You might have other errors as well, but let's start there.

Per [tools doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/java.html) -cp classpath
    Specify a list of directories, JAR archives, and ZIP archives to search for class files. **Class path entries are separated by semicolons (;)**. Specifying -classpath or -cp overrides any setting of the CLASSPATH environment variable.

Comment: Ok.. i was successfully about my code. this compile error cause i'am using this (”), should this code using (") no (”). Thanks about your attention sir.

Comment: Great to hear. Throw it in an answer and accept it so the question closes.